# svchost.exe drawing 25% CPU constantly

Tags: svchost, cpu-load

svchost.exe is drawing 25% CPU and causing constant fan spin on my Lenovo T460s.  Any ideas how to detect what is causing this and how to get rid of it?

I disabled the DNS client but that doesn't seem to change anything.

Edit: It is wuaueng.dll causing the load. Just saw that using Process Explorer.

Comment: So you’re using Windows 7 I guess?

Comment: Yes I am. Any ideas?

Comment: It's part of Windows Update. Is this happening over several hours/days? If not, it's probably just working normally trying to check/download updates.

Answer (score 0):

Be patient, this stuff takes a while to get rid of.
Try full system scans of your computer with various software (e.g. Malwarebytes, ComboFix might be too brutal and cause unnecessary issues)
Try the recommended Microsoft fixes 
Download and install  KB3153199 then do a manual update. Reboot the computer and immediately install the update. Do a manual update and wait about 15 minutes.

https://  www.microsoft  .com  /en-us/download/details.aspx?id=52232

Edit: If the above does not get you updates install the following KB. This resolved my April update problem. The above KB3153199 resolved the May update issue. It seems this will be a monthly issue with Windows 7.

https://  www.microsoft  .com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51853

Try also this one ( https://  support.microsoft  .com/en-us/kb/947821 it helped a LOT, probably fixed the issue. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2509997 didnt help at all).
- You had to let this software run for multiple hours, so be patient. It might look stuck but it is working and doing it's job. (That was quite a surprise, to be entirely honest)

And last but not least - Consider a paid anti-virus software.

http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/t/614278/windows-7-svchostexe-netsvcs-at-25-cpu-usage-windows-update-impossible/

Answer (score -1):

SOLVED!
I killed the client Windows Update.